# What happens when one drops a commit in between?

Tags: git

Imagine I'm doing `git rebase -i 63569c41040b8fecce5c43a40745888c0283f429`:

```
pick b444c0b second
pick 604539e third

# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

The first commit added a file `example.txt` with the content:

```
a
```

The second commit modified the file `example.txt` to

```
a1
b
c
```

The third commit changed the file `example.txt` to

```
d
a1
cx
```

What happens when the second commit is dropped? What is the content of the file `example.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto 63569c4
Last commands done (2 commands done):
   d b444c0b second
   pick 604539e Third
No commands remaining.
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '63569c4'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   example.txt
```

with

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
a
=======
d
a1
cx
>>>>>>> 604539e... Third
```

So the answer is that you have to manually resolve that.

Comment: @g19fanatic I didn't know what to expect. I could not find the answer, so I tried it and thought it might be interesting enough to tell others, too.